# Magento - Get Attribute Set Group Name

Tags: magento

Sorry I got my initial question wrong.

<s>I want to get the attribute set name in the compare products page (the page that compares products side by side)</s>

I want to get the Group names, that fall under the attribute set. U know how the attribute sets are maintained ( Attribute Set > Groups > Attributes ) So that I can display the compare page product attributes by group name. How can I get the group names?

I'm not sure how to do this, can someone point me to the right code or right direction?

The template being used for this page is the default one at:
template\catalog\product\compare\list.phtml

Answer (score 1):

To fetch the attribute set name in the compare products page, you can try the following code in your `template\catalog\product\compare\list.phtml`

After this line of code

```
<?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
```

Paste this code to print your attribute set name

```
// Get attribute set model.
$model = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set');

// Get attribute set id.
$attributeSetId = $_item->getAttributeSetId();
$attributeSet = $model->load($attributeSetId);

// This is attribute set name.
$attributeSetName = $attributeSet->getAttributeSetName();

echo $attributeSetName;
```

The above code will print your attribute set name and based on your HTML requirement, you can alter the code.

Comment: Sorry slimshadddyyy, i ur answer was helpful but it made me realize that my question was wrong. I'm actually trying to get the group names so I could display the group names above the attributes that belong to that group under the product comparison page.

Comment: You can try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090527/how-to-get-the-attribute-group-in-magento